# Cannot query firebase relationalship object - Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Been trying to follow firebase's [simple turtial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) how to set up and strcture your database. Im using the Realtime Database (minimal example):

**Data:**

```
posts: {
    <postId>: {
        title: "some title",
        comments: {
            <commentId>: true
        }
    }
}

comments: {
    <commentId>: {
        name: "Kevin",
        text: "no no no no"
    }
}
```

**Rules:**

```
{
    "rules": {
        "posts": {
            "$postId": {
                ".read": true
            }
        },
        "comments": {
            "$commentId": {
                ".read": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**JS:**

```
[...]   
let database = firebase.database();
let callback = function(snap) { console.log( snap.val() };

// $postId already set
database.ref(`/posts/${postId}`).limitToLast(12).on('child_added', callback);
```

In my console log is always true. I cannot find a tutorial that shows this kind of setup with rules, data and query. When I go to that URL I expect to see the list of comments object:

```
12345: {name: ..., text: ...},
67890: {name: ..., text: ...},
[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load the comments from that post, attach the listener to its `comments` child node:

```
database.ref(`/posts/${postId}/comments`).limitToLast(12).on('child_added', callback);
```

If you want to see the key of each comment and its value, make sure to log both:

```
let callback = function(snap) { console.log(snap.key, snap.val()); };
```

Comment: Many thnaks. That does work but I've now switched to firestore 